# Does there exist a $20\times20$ boolean matrix such that no two $3\times3$ submatrices are identical?

Tags: combinatorics

I want to create  a 20*20 boolean  matrix that i will be converting to something like a square  bar code.
 I will be looking on this matrix through  a 3*3 window, and what i want is every time i randomly move this window it gives me a unique 3*3 matrix,  so i can determine  where the window is by comparing it to the big matrix.
Thanks

Comment: more of a SO question if you ask me

Comment: Seems rather clear to me. Does there exist a $20\times20$ grid of ones and zeros such that no two $3\times3$ subgrids are identical?

Comment: @RushabhMehta This is in the realm of combinatorics. It is like a two dimensional de Bruijn sequence.

Comment: If your window only looks at touching 3*3 squares, there are $18\times18$ different squares. Now there are $2^9=512$ different $3\times3$ boolean squares, so in theory, it could be possible...

Comment: Doing some experimentation with Python, I found (with random matrices) that for sizes greater than $12\times12$, the problem doesn't seem to have solutions... So $20\times20$ seems to be out of reach (however, as those random matrices contain roughly the same amount of ones and zeros, there could be hidden solutions!).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution using simulated annealing:

```
11110000100110110010
00010111100011011001
10011101100100110100
00000001010010111111
11011101010000001011
01001100101111111100
11000110100010001011
00000111101000010011
01011110010001100011
10111101101000001010
00000110011011001100
10000000111100110110
00101011011100100011
10001011101001101010
10111110101111011011
00101110011110101001
01111001100110010100
01101010101111110110
10010000101000100100
11111101000010100010
```

Comment: Could you explain the method?

Comment: [Simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing).  The basic move was to flip a single bit.  The score function was the number of distinct windows.

Comment: Do you remember how many step the annealing process took?

Comment: One try I gave up after 4160000 steps.  The next succeeded in 209899 steps.